# how to fetch results from select query with class

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to learn select query with class.
Below is index.php, which have a form to display results and I in PHP I am calling class operations, which is in operations.php

```
<?php
        session_start();
        include('operations.php');
        $userprofileobj = new operations();
        $userprofileobj->showuserprofile($_SESSION['user_email']);
        $row = $userprofileobj->fetch_assoc();
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" name="number_validate" id="number_validate" >
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Admin Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" name="min" id="min"  value="<?php echo $row['user_name']; ?>" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">User Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" name="max" id="max" value="<?php echo $row['user_email']; ?>" required />
            </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success">
          </div>
   </form>
```

**operations.php is:**

```
class operations{

public $user_email;
public $error;
public $con;


public function __construct()
{       
    $this->con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","admin_with_oops");
}
public function showuserprofile($user_email)
{
    $result = $this->con->query("select * from user_table where user_email='$user_email'");
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {

        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->error = "User not exist";
    }
}
 }
```

Am I on right way? If yes teh what is the problem on above code?

**Error is: Fatal error: Call to undefined method operations::fetch_assoc() in F:\xampp\htdocs\admin_with_oops\HTML\index.php on line 16**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$userprofileobj` is an instance of the `operations` class. It doesn't have `fetch_assoc()` method. You should replace

```
$userprofileobj->showuserprofile($_SESSION['user_email']);
$row = $userprofileobj->fetch_assoc();
```

with

```
$row = $userprofileobj->showuserprofile($_SESSION['user_email'])->fetch_assoc();
```

Or you could assign the result to a variable and then call the `fetch_assoc()` function on it:

```
$result = $userprofileobj->showuserprofile($_SESSION['user_email']);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: @vinodjaiswal See my edit. Your code doesn't work because returning the result in the `showuserprofile()` function doesn't change the `$userprofileobj` variable.